# proper way of doing a left join with linq to entity?

Tags: linq-to-entities

since [DefaultIfEmpty()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738638.aspx) is not supported, what is the proper way of doing a left join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the end, I used [the let way](http://oddiandeveloper.blogspot.com/2008/12/testable-left-outer-join-in-linq-to.html) with **.FirstOrDefault()**

```
from myothertable
where....
let var = (query).FirstOrDefault()
select new {otherfield, var.field1, var.field2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say how to solve your problem, since you don't say what it is, but generally:

```
var q = from i in Context.Invoices
        select new 
        {
            Number = i.Number,
            ItemNumbers = from il in i.Lines
                          select il.Number
        }
```

LINQ to Entities will coalesce nulls, so you get an empty collection if there are no invoice line items.

Now this produces a graph, rather than a tabular result set. My wild guess is that's what you want, since when you work in LINQ to Entities you generally want to work with objects, rather than tabular SQL results. But like you said, it's hard to be more specific without knowing the precise problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: when I put in many field from the same table, the end result,(sql query) use a lot of unionall stuff

Comment: I can't suggest a good answer based on so little information.